# CSS strange effect on login form, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

just start play around with HTML and CSS, i'm try to create a Signup form.

After apply some css to my html i'm having a strane behavior once i click on the input box, see gif attached. Looks like my form change opacity on click.

[image: strange]

Here the code

```css
.body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #0b5ad0, #0794e7, #004093, #0069bf);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.center{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .5;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: calc(50%/2) ;
    top: 25%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}


.title{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2vh;
}

.cont{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0.5vh;

}

label{
    font-size: 1.5vh;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 0.5vh;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">

</head>
<body class="body">

        <div class="center">
            <h1 class="title">Sign Up New User</h1>

            <form class="submit_form">
                <div class="cont">
                    <label for="Name">First name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="Name" name="fname">
                </div>
                <div class="cont">
                    <label for="Surname">Surname:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="Surname" name="fsurname">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks like the opacity 0.5 on your .center styling is coming through.

Comment: From your code snippet, I can't reproduce your issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ".center" class, I remove **Opacity:0.5** and add use RGB color like this **background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);** for set transparent background.

```css
.body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #0b5ad0, #0794e7, #004093, #0069bf);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.center{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
    color: #fff;
   
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: calc(50%/2) ;
    top: 25%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}


.title{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2vh;
}

.cont{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0.5vh;

}

label{
    font-size: 1.5vh;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 0.5vh;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">

</head>
<body class="body">

        <div class="center">
            <h1 class="title">Sign Up New User</h1>

            <form class="submit_form">
                <div class="cont">
                    <label for="Name">First name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="Name" name="fname">
                </div>
                <div class="cont">
                    <label for="Surname">Surname:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="Surname" name="fsurname">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```